# how do I create a pipe using popen and communicate through it in Python?

Tags: python, pipe

I have a process that writes to stdout and reads from stdin. I would like, in Python, to use that process to read and write from its stdout/stdin.

I tried:

```
      process = Popen(['the_program_name'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
```

and then I try to use

```
      process.stdout.readline()
```

and

```
      process.stdin.write('input to the_program_name')
```

but that doesn't work...

any ideas how to do that?

EDIT:

the program seems to block on the readline statement, after the write statement. If I use process.communicate then I get the output back, but the external process immediately terminates.

Comment: proc.stdout.readline() will wait until it can return that line. Are you sure that you shouldn't first give some input to the subproccess in question to get the result? Also, if you aren't using stderr at all, you may want to close it: proc.stderr.close()

Comment: I actually use the write statement first, @Dalen.

Comment: I found the problem. it was because the "the_program" needed to flush its stdout.

Answer (score 0):

Read [here](https://pymotw.com/2/subprocess/):

Relevant code:

```
import subprocess

print '\npopen2:'

proc = subprocess.Popen(['cat', '-'],
                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        )
stdout_value = proc.communicate('through stdin to stdout')[0]
print '\tpass through:', repr(stdout_value)
```

Comment: This doesn't allow buffering and direct access to process's stdin/stdout/stderr

Comment: I tested this code, it works as advertised, care to explain? It doesn't include `stderr`

Comment: @Ishay this seems to close the process (i.e. it sends ^D) -- i want to continuously interact with the process and not just through one statement.